# Validating financial transactions on INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm writing the schema for a database handling monetary transactions between accounts that potentially hold balances in different currencies.

I want to ensure that a transaction only succeeds if both the source account and destination account have the same currency as that of the transaction, else rollback and signal an error. So far I have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER transactions_same_currencies BEFORE INSERT
   ON "Transactions" FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.same_currencies();
```

where I define `same_currencies()` as

```
DECLARE s integer;
DECLARE d integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT s = currency_id
        FROM Accounts a
        WHERE a.id = NEW.source_id;
    SELECT d = currency_id
    FROM Accounts a
    WHERE a.id = NEW.destination_id;
    IF NEW.currency_id <> @s
        OR NEW.currency_id <> @d
    THEN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END IF;
END;
```

Apart from whether my code is correct, I'd also like to know if I should be doing this in a trigger, and where to put any other validation I need (I wrote non-negative account balances as a check constraint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to review your data structure and enforce this type of constraint using foreign key references, rather than a trigger.

It appears that the `Transactions` table has both accounts and the currency for the transaction.  Each account also has a currency.  You can enforce what you want by having the (account, currency) pair be a foreign key reference.  This eliminates the need for a trigger for enforcement.  You will need an index on the (account, currency) pair in `Accounts`.

Comment: Thanks! I used `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX`. Would it be possible just to put a unique constraint on (account, currency) in `Accounts`, without adding an index, seeing as 'account' is already indexed?

Comment: @topynate . . . A unique constraint is implemented using a unique index, so there is no way to avoid the index.